# Difficulties with Typescript args type inference

Tags: reactjs, typescript, inference

I am having trouble understanding an inference error. The ts linter underline `(event: E)` of  `useCallback` with the message bellow.
When I cast the callback of `useCallback` with `as T` the linter message is gone. Is there any way to avoid doing this? What did I didn't understand?

**Complete code:**

```
import { DependencyList, useCallback } from 'react'

const useStopBubblingCallback = <T extends (event: E) => any, E extends Event = Event>(
  callback: T,
  deps: DependencyList
) : T =>
  useCallback<T>((event: E) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    event.preventDefault()
    return callback(event)
  }, deps)

export default useStopBubblingCallback
```

**Linter message:**

```
Argument of type '(event: E) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  '(event: E) => any' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', 
but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 
'(event: E) => any'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `useStopBubblingCallback` to the following signature ([example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQKZlQOwCZYMYCeAMsAM4wA0cArqagMICGANswEaN4DWcAvnADMoEEHADkUVJxhiAULLwRM5GnQDKMCGABC1Nm2bBMAcyasO3OAF44AHgCicVAA8YWbKTj2Ablng2fPwA%20AApZODg8FnZOLgAuOBDUX0wYBPsASmsguEZMAgpwuFwwUgS0DBx8YjIYWSyEpJS0ryyrHLyCbKLaBmiLLhCmv3S2nIQiiOS-ADpyLQAFYTBGY0YYYCUQjMmnZpmwSWa0AUZqZhht3ckYaihMSP7Y4dSdiN4qEtId2RdIWGKqFO53gvQ0Wl0%20kMJjMMW48kUyng3msqlQ4J0egMRlMT24Q2mqQSAFkIL1Aq9sogPnAANoAXSyAHomXBvI1CS1SeTmmNcvkgA)):

```
const useStopBubblingCallback = <E extends Event = Event>(
  callback: (event: E) => any,
  deps: DependencyList
) : (event: E) => any =>
  useCallback((event: E) => { /*your code*/ }, deps)

const cb = useStopBubblingCallback((event: MouseEvent) => {}, []) 
// cb: (event: MouseEvent) => any
```

Note, that in your case type parameter `E` had no inference candidate in the outer function, so TypeScript cannot do anything useful with `E` (it would be fixed to `Event` all the time).

We also drop the manual type argument in `useCallback<T>` to let the compiler automatically infer its type.